# Wordpress get first image from a post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, echo

Trying to get the first image from a post, but my php code doesn't return anything, any help?

```
<?php while ($browndog_blog->have_posts()) : $browndog_blog->the_post();                    
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
   'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
    );

    $attachments = get_children( $args );

    //print_r($attachments);

    if ($attachments) {
        foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' )  ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ) : wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );

            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ).'"></a>';
            echo '<p>'.get_the_excerpt($post->ID).'</p>';
            echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More</a></p>';
        }
    }
endwhile; ?>
```

Not sure what's going wrong as I'm using a similar code to get all of the image attachments and not just one, and that works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the first image assoc with a WP post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332979/how-to-get-the-first-image-assoc-with-a-wp-post)

Answer (score 1):

`get_children()` only returns images that have been uploaded directly to that post. If an image has been attached to a given post it will not be considered one it's children and thus wont be returned by the afore mentioned function.

An easy way to check a post's children is login to the dashboard and go to posts, edit post. Click the `Add Media` button above the editor and from the only drop down box select `Uploaded to this post`. If this is empty then get_children will not return any images regardless of the post's content.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just did the same thing as you are looking to do... I won't claim to be a guru, but here's what I did to get this working and with any luck you will be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
$image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id();
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,’large’);
$image_url=$image_url[0];
```

Basically the first image in the array is the thumbnail, as I understand it, so that's why I grab the thumbnail id first, then use it to retrieve the large version of the image.